# wc_get_products() not return the images details

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api, api

When I try to fetch products using the official REST API, returned `product` contains the a property named `images` which is an array and contains the URL to image of product.
But when I fetch using this method, it fetches other details but not the image.

```
    $productsQuery= wc_get_products(array(
        'limit' => 10,
        'status' => 'publish',
    ));
    $products = array();
    foreach ($productsQuery as $product) {
        $products[] = $product->get_data();
    }
    return new WP_REST_Response($products, 200);
```

how can I make this to return the `images` property as well.

Answer (score 2):

The [WC_Product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) object has an `image_id` (string) and an `gallery_image_ids` (array) attribute for product image and product's gallery images. Both of them are attachment ids, so you should get the image src from it's attachment id with the [`wp_get_attachment_image_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/) method and add it to your `$products` array.

Comment: I already tried a similar solution, but getting this error
`Call to undefined method WC_Product_Simple::wp_get_attachment_image_url()`

Comment: There is no such method `WC_Product_Simple::wp_get_attachment_image_url()`. You should call the method by itself.
`$image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachment_id )`. Read the method docs.

Comment: alright, I did, but the problem is that It gives the `html` tag not although it includes the src, but can I somehow get just URL of image ?

Comment: @Lint I think you called `wp_get_attachment_image()` function instead. It returns the html tag. The function that I mentioned is `wp_get_attachment_image_url()` which gives you the source of image.

Comment: Alright, thanks.
Just a little question.
When I use `wc_get_product(PRODUCT_ID)` function, it returns some properties not all.
But when I retrieve the same product using WooCommerce REST API URL.
It returns all the data that is returned by above mentioned method, also it includes images and other attributes automatically.
Can I get the same properties using a local function and not the rest api url ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Lint Look at WC_Product methods and properties. All you can get is in there. And based of documentations there is no way to get product image src directly, you should use each image's unique ID.
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html

Comment: If it's not possible, how does REST API returns then ? I wonder

Comment: @Lint I didn't read the REST API code responsible for this but I think they probably get image src from it's unique id or they read it directly from DB.